# Reducing image to vectors in rgee

Tags: r, rgee

I am using the package rgee in R to process satellite data via GEE.

I have a Feature Collection: `Counties<-ee$FeatureCollection('users/stephherbstritt/Counties')`

And an image: `corn16<-ee$Image('users/stephherbstritt/corn2016')`

I filtered the Feature Collection to one county boundary.

```
AOI <- Counties$
  filter(
    ee$Filter$eq(
      'COUNTY_NAM',
      'MONTOUR'))
```

Then I clipped the AOI to the image. `shp16<-corn16$clip(AOI)`

Now I would like to convert the clipped image (shp16) to a feature so I can use it as the bound to filter the bounds of a request to get satellite data.

I tried:

````
    geometry = AOI,
    scale = 30,
    geometryType = "polygon",
    eightConnected = FALSE,
    labelProperty = "zone",
    reducer = ee$Reducer$count()
)```

But I am getting an error when I try to map the result (test) to check it. 

ERROR: 
``` Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  EEException: Image.reduceToVectors: Need 1+1 bands for Reducer.count, image has 1.```
````

Answer (score 0):

I ended up trying:

```r
shp16a<-shp16$reduceToVectors(
  scale= 10,
  geometry= AOI,
  geometryType= 'polygon',
  maxPixels= 1e8)
```

And it seems to work but later in the code, I exceed the EE user memory limit when I try to calculate the means of a band in my area. So I think there must be a better way to do this?

```r
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  EEException: User memory limit exceeded.
```